# Print all iframe buttons from sql name

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, iframe

In the table 'Facebook' I have 1 column, 'name'. In the column 'name' I have Facebook name pages. How do I print all the Facebook iframe buttons?

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = '';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = '';
    $db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$result=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Facebook");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo "http://www.facebook.com/$row['name']"; ?>&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
}
?>
```

Comment: `href=<?php echo ...` You are opening a `php` tag while you are already in PHP code.

Comment: I'm try this but not work href=echo "http://www.facebook.com/$row['name']"

Comment: Please update your question with what you've changed.

Comment: I am make this but not work
echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=echo "http://www.facebook.com/$row['name']"&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';

Comment: Please update the question because it's not clear at all in comments (the link is replaced, I can't read it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stating variable as string. In (`$row['name'])` the code is just taking `$row`  as array not the array key. Use the code below

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = '';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = '';
    $db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$result=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Facebook");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/ ' . $row['name'] . '&amp;......';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Your using PHP tags withing PHP. Remove the tags and use `' . $variable . '`. Look up [string concatination](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to learn more.

```
echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/ ' . $row['name'] . '&amp;......';
```